# PostgreSQL: Cannot use numbers as tags for dollar quoted strings

Tags: postgresql, dollar-quoting

How do we use numbers as tags for dollar quoted strings?

```
INSERT INTO table(user_id,user_data) 
values (22176,to_jsonb($123${"name": "Helo. $ what is this $"}$123$::jsonb))
```

The above query fails, however if I replace numeric tags with alphabetic then it works. I didn't find anything in the documentation against using numbers for tags.

I need to make my tags as unique as possible, since I'm trying to avoid a situation where user content inside the jsonb matches my tags, for example

```
$abc${"name": "hello $abc$"}$abc$
```

I was trying to use UUIDs but it's not accepting numbers as tags.

**Note:** It's an example query, I have a lot of `'` in my json values.

Comment: Why use dollar quoting at all here? Do you have embedded `'` in your JSON values?

Comment: yes, a lot of it is user input, which contains a lot apostrophes.

Comment: Why no just use some kind of prefix + some random numbers?  e.g. `$a123${"name": "Helo. $ what is this $"}$a123$::jsonb` or a uuid without the dashes: `select $_2e4363fdcbf74396a8731a3b6a76c917${"name": "Helo. $ what is this $"}$_2e4363fdcbf74396a8731a3b6a76c917$::jsonb`

Comment: Note that either `to_jsonb()` or  the case `::jsonb` is unnecessary. You only need on of those. I'd go for the cast.

Comment: If that is user input, you should be using placeholder with a prepared statement and not literals `insert into ... values (?, cast(? as jsonb))`  - the syntax depends on the programming language you are using

Comment: i've to update like at most 10000 rows, which i'm doing in a single query. i pass all the values as `(//value),(//value)...` string. I tried parameterized by passing the values string, but it didn't accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `$123$`, because PostgreSQL uses `$1`, `$2` etc. as placeholders in prepared statements.  `$a1$` would be ok.

To get a rare string to avoid collisions, drop on the keyboard a few times and make sure not to hit a digit first.